# Distinguish among "symbol-constituent characters", "symbol-constituents", and "word constituents"

Tags: regex, emacs

The regexp part of Emacs manual seems confusing w.r.t. the above three concepts.

I list out my interpretations of the explanations below first:

1. "symbol-constituents" is mutually exclusive with "word constituents";
2. "symbol-constituent characters" includes both "symbol-constituents" and "word constituents"

Is this correct understanding?
And below are the relevant quotes from the manual:
-quote 1:

> Word constituents: ‘w’:
>   Parts of words in human languages. These are typically used in variable and command names in programs. All upper- and lower-case letters, and the digits, are typically word constituents.

-quote 2:

> Symbol constituents: ‘_’:
>   Extra characters used in variable and command names along with word constituents. Examples include the characters ‘$&*+-*<>’ in Lisp mode, which may be part of a symbol name even though they are not part of English words. In standard C, the only non-word-constituent character that is valid in symbols is underscore (‘*’).
>   [quote 1 and 2](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html)

-quote 3:

> \_<: 
>   matches the empty string, but only at the beginning of a symbol. A symbol is a sequence of one or more symbol-constituent characters. A symbol-constituent character is a character whose syntax is either ‘w’ or ‘_’. ‘_<’ matches at the beginning of the buffer only if a symbol-constituent character follows.
>   [quote 3](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that "symbol-constituent characters" *should* only be used to mean characters which are themselves symbol-constituents (and therefore, as you correctly understand, not word-constituent).

Your quote three is indeed confusing, but that wording has since been fixed. In my Emacs (from trunk, about three months ago) it reads:

```
`\_<'
     matches the empty string, but only at the beginning of a symbol.  A
     symbol is a sequence of one or more word or symbol constituent
     characters.  `\_<' matches at the beginning of the buffer (or
     string) only if a symbol-constituent character follows.

`\_>'
     matches the empty string, but only at the end of a symbol.  `\_>'
     matches at the end of the buffer (or string) only if the contents
     end with a symbol-constituent character.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I did a test and it seems that "symbol-constituent characters" includes "word constituents". Test: create a new buffer in c-mode with only `$` (which is a "word constituent", per syntax table), search the buffer with regex `\_<`, and it matches to "|$". (but if you search for symbol constituent, `\s_`, it will fail.)

Comment: That behaviour is consistent with the revised text I've quoted. It now states that `\_<` matches the start of any sequence of *word constituent* **or** *symbol constituent* characters. In your example it is matching the start of a sequence comprised of a single word constituent. The difference is that the revised documentation no longer implies the existence of a third class of characters called "symbol-constituent characters" which combines the two types of syntax.

Comment: So a "symbol" may contain *both* word-constituent characters and symbol-constituent characters. But the terms "symbol-constituent [character]" and "word-constituent [character]" themselves are very specifically about their own mutually-exclusive syntax classes, and there is no similar term which refers to a character from *either* syntax class.

Comment: I see. So in the original quote (3), the _symbol-constituent characters_ indeed include include _symbol constituents_ and _word constituents_. But such wording is too confusing, and hence the concept is removed. I will take a look /search for the updated wording instead of the one on the link.

Comment: Yes indeed. I presume that someone reviewing that text noticed (as you did) that the concepts were being mixed in a confusing and unhelpful way, and consequently the text was improved.